# Google Fit "Connected apps" - How do you get an app to appear in the "Settings"->"Connected apps" list?

Tags: java, android, google-fit

Where can I find the information to get my app to show up in "Connected apps" in the Google Fit settings? See the example below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found it was a simple matter of:

1) [signing the app](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-reading-sensor-data--cms-25723),

2) installing signed app via [ADB](http://help.gamesalad.com/gamesalad-cookbook/testing/ad-hoc-test-on-your-android-device/4-06-ad-hoc-testing-on-an-android-device/) (not instarun), **- this was my problem**

3) and implementing [Google Fit Api](https://developers.google.com/fit/) (using the "[BasicRecordingsApi](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicRecordingApi)" for [example](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples)*)

So far I haven't found any info on cost/pricing, but since it's using the Google API quotas, that could be a consideration going forward.
[image]
*Don't forget to update gradle! :)